# Hashtable/Map: where to start

Tags: algorithm, performance, vector, hashmap, hashtable

I am looking to make a function that takes a string and returns a value that is in an dynamic's array range, basically, a dynamic hash-table, But I'm rather confused on where to start, I have the vector down, but I don't know which hashing function would be good for perhaps runtime performance -- I want it to be fast and with no collisions, therefore, I would love if you could share some resources on candidate implementations or algorithms

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is alot of factors to have in consideration. One is the size of the hash table. A hash table is only good if there is no colisions so a big prime number will do, however if the number is to big u will waste alot of memory, you have to take in consideration how much data you are expecting. Same case happens if your prime is to low, u are force to create remake the hash.

There is 2 solution that im aware of to prevent the colisions:
U can create another hash or array list inside of your hash everytime a collision happens.

Or u can also everytime a colision happen try to put that info in the next free space of your hash table.

Comment: It is going to be dynamic, so I just want a good hashing function that takes a string and returns a value.

Comment: Well i still gave u the 2 options u can choose, i would recomend the 1st. Everytime a colision occur u create a hash in that spot. In other words if a colision occurs whit the words "hello" and "world" u would create a second hash in that place that ,for example uses like part of the string. Another thing u can try is use sha256 on your keys instead of the string that way u know it would never match.